# WooCommerce Webhooks Custom/Action not saving

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks

Every time you try and set a custom/action topic within webhooks **(from WooCommerce > Settings > Webhooks)** it would unset it as soon as you update your changes to the webhook. *In other words, it will undo your custom topic and return it back to 'Select an option' for the topic dropdown.*

Any help at all is appreciated. Thank you very much!

edit: In addition to my comment below, I've also attempted to create my own custom topic via the following filter `woocommerce_webhook_topic_hooks`, however, it doesn't show within the dropdown list as an option.

The below code runs from `functions.php` as with any WordPress hook..

**Code**

```
function custom_woocommerce_webhook_topics( $topic ) {
    $topic['order.refunded'] = array(
        'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta',
        'woocommerce_api_edit_order',
        'woocommerce_order_edit_status',
        'woocommerce_order_status_changed'
    );

    return $topic;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_webhook_topic_hooks', 'custom_woocommerce_webhook_topics', 10, 1 );
```

edit 2: Added more context

Comment: Why the downvotes? If more info is needed I'm happy to provide it. I've gone through the docs available at: http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#webhooks. I've gone through hours of Google searches and poured over Woos source code even, but cannot find an answer to any of it as there isn't much info on custom webhooks anywhere.

Comment: What do you mean by "unset as soon as you update your changes"? Is the topic no longer visible? Your webhook configuration won't save for the custom topic? Which file contains the code in your question?

Comment: The downvotes are because the question is unclear. Please elaborate, specifically on the questions that doublesharp has posed. Consider explaining what precisely you are trying to do and what is happening versus what you expect. You have to ask a good question to get a good answer.

Comment: @doublesharp Unset as in it returns back to default i.e. 'Select an option'. Code is within the functions.php file..

Comment: @helgatheviking I'm not certain how familiar you are with WP/WC, but webhooks are pretty much dead to the point. The problem i'm having which I've described above is simple, it refuses to let you set a custom/action topic for the webhook either through the UI or via the filter for no explained reason that I could find.

Comment: I'm extremely familiar with WooCommerce, but I still don't understand your question, which is why I seconded doublesharps request for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue. Selecting any of the built-in topics worked fine. But selection Action and entering any WooCommerce Subscription actions kept reverting. I had also tried creating a new custom topic in the same file (wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-subscriptions/includes/class-wcs-webhooks.php) that the built-in topics are created, mirroring 1:1 the code of one of the topics that 'stick' (e.g subscription.created) for a new 'subscription.paymentcomplete' topic. It appears in the drop down, but after saving the drop-down reverts to the default 'Selection an option...'.

```
//wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-subscriptions/includes/class-wcs-webhooks.php


public static function init() {

    ...
    add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_created_for_order', __CLASS__ . '::add_subscription_created_callback', 10, 2 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete', __CLASS__ . '::add_subscription_payment_complete_callback', 10,  );
    ...
}

public static function add_topics( $topic_hooks, $webhook ) {

    if ( 'subscription' == $webhook->get_resource() ) {
        $topic_hooks = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_webhook_topics', array(
            'subscription.created' => array(
                'wcs_api_subscription_created',
                'wcs_webhook_subscription_created',
                'woocommerce_process_shop_subscription_meta',
            ),
            'subscription.paymentcomplete' => array(
                'wcs_webhook_subscription_payment_complete'
                'woocommerce_process_shop_subscription_meta',
            ),
            ...
        ), $webhook );
    }

    return $topic_hooks;
}

public static function add_topics_admin_menu( $topics ) {

    $front_end_topics = array(
        'subscription.created' => __( ' Subscription Created', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ),
        'subscription.paymentcomplete' => __( ' Subscription Payment Complete', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ),
        ...
    );

    return array_merge( $topics, $front_end_topics );
}

public static function add_subscription_created_callback( $order, $subscription ) {
    do_action( 'wcs_webhook_subscription_created', $subscription->id );
}

public static function add_subscription_payment_complete_callback( $order, $subscription ) {
    do_action( 'wcs_webhook_subscription_payment_complete', $subscription->id );
}
```

The solution was:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_valid_webhook_events', __CLASS__ . '::add_event', 10, 1 );

public static function add_event( $events) {

        $events[] = 'paymentcomplete';

        return $events;
}
```

Comment: Hey mate, I did eventually dig up the root cause of the issue. These weren't included/working in the version of WooCommerce that I was using. I believe it was some kind of a bug or missing code. I was forced to upgrade WooCommerce (which was a huge gamble due to it being a major version) and it finally worked properly without any issues what so ever.

Comment: I'll keep an eye out on this post incase you need more help as this was a pain in the butt problem so I feel yu.

Comment: I worked out what the actual issue is: The topic was invalid. WC validates the parts of the topic name as "{resource}.{event}". By default (see wc-conditional-functions.php) the only valid resources are "order,product,coupon". class-wcs-webhooks.php adds 'subscription' as a new resource but, what was need is to add 'paymentcomplete' (or in your case 'refunded' as a new valid event.